# Create a repeat symbol in XAML / WPF

Tags: wpf, xaml, icons

I need to create a repeat symbol in XAML / WPF (procedural code would be ok too, though I'd prefer XAML if possible), something like the following, but I just need the not finished circle with the arrow (the white drawing in the button): 
http://www.vista-style-icons.com/libs/phone/repeat.htm

I know how to create a circle in XAML, but I don't know how to create a not finished circle and add an arrow to the open end?
Thank you for any help!

Comment: u can use <Path Stroke="White" StrokeThickness="5" Data="{Binding data}" />

Comment: Well, the problem is not how to bind the data, but which data I need (solved by Quartermeisters answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create an unfinished circle by using an [ArcSegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.arcsegment.aspx) as a path segment in a [Path](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.shapes.path.aspx) shape.  You specify the start and end point of the arc and the radius of the entire circle.  You can render it on top of a blue circle by putting them in a grid:

```
<Grid Width="160" Height="160">
    <Ellipse Fill="Blue"/>
    <Path StrokeThickness="5" Stroke="White">
        <Path.Data>
            <PathGeometry>
                <PathFigure StartPoint="115,45">
                    <ArcSegment Point="115,115" Size="50,50" IsLargeArc="True"/>
                </PathFigure>
            </PathGeometry>
        </Path.Data>
    </Path>
    <Polygon Points="115,115 105,105 125,105 125,125" Fill="White"/>
</Grid>
```

You can also use the shorter [Path Markup Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752293.aspx) to create a StreamGeometry rather than a PathGeometry:

```
<Grid Width="160" Height="160">
    <Ellipse Fill="Blue"/>
    <Path Data="M 115,45 A 50,50 0 1 0 115,115"
        StrokeThickness="5" Stroke="White"/>
    <Polygon Points="115,115 105,105 125,105 125,125" Fill="White"/>
</Grid>
```

You'll need to work on it to get exactly the look you want, but that should give you the basic technique for drawing an unfinished circle with an arrow.

Comment: Thank you very much Quartermeister, this gives me exactly the look I want :-)